# Create an Observable the starts from a merge

Tags: angular, merge, rxjs

I have an array of Observables that all emit the same data types, and I want to merge this array into a single Observable.

It seems that I need to use the [merge operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge) and pass it the array, but I don't know how to create the target Observable for the merge operator.

I'm thinking the code would be something like this:

```
let arr: Observable<Event>[] = getArray(); 
let o = new Observable();
return o.merge(arr);
```

I don't know if the above is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the static [`merge`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-merge) method:

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/merge";

let arr: Observable<Event>[] = getArray(); 
let o = Observable.merge(...arr);
```

Comment: For some reason WebStorm would not see merge as a static member unless I manually imported it. Usually it shows a hint to import RxJs statics so I was struggling as there are both a static and operator method called merge. Thanks for the help.